# Refresh context in Android

Tags: android, android-context

I don't know if I understand the problem correctly, but I have a weird issue. I have list which I am getting from Parse.com server and I filter the data by "tags". Sometimes I change "tags" with DialogFragment and refresh the lists, but after 2-3 change the list is showing wrong data. I have debugged it and it seems that wrong data is being taken from Database, which is weird because in another Fragment window the same method returns correct answers. 
Here is how I get list from Parse :

```
YoursEventsAsync yoursEventsAsync = new YoursEventsAsync(Constants.LIMIT, getActivity());
        yoursEventsAsync.asyncResponse = this;
        yoursEventsAsync.execute();
```

Then, in this AsyncTask I am getting data like this :

```
@SafeVarargs
@Override
protected final ArrayList<Event> doInBackground(ArrayList<Event>... params) {
    return ParseAdapter.getInstance().getEventsFromServer(limit, context);
}
```

And this is my main function responsible for getting sometimes good sometimes bad data :

```
public ArrayList<Event> getEventsFromServer(int limit, Context context) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Event");
    query.whereContainedIn("tags", DatabaseAdapter.getTagNames(context));
    query.setLimit(limit);
    query.include("createdBy");
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        List<ParseObject> parseEvents = query.find();
        events = setEventList(parseEvents);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return events;
}
```

I have debugged the 3rd line and it sometimes works fine and sometimes not.

Here is DatabaseAdapter.getTagNames method :

```
public static List<String> getTagNames(Context context) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
    RealmQuery<Tag> query = realm.where(Tag.class);
    RealmResults<Tag> tagResults = query.findAll();
    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Tag tag : tagResults) {
        tags.add(tag.getName());
    }
    return tags;
}
```

As I have said earlier, if I open another fragment, which uses the same method 'getTagNames' it works fine. That's why I think the problem is with context. Is it possible that AsyncTask is somehow remembering the context and retrieveing the old one?

Comment: It's difficult to say, however I have never experienced an issue with an old `Context` reference. As far as I know, Realm for Android is relatively new which means you may have stumbled upon a bug (or a feature). With that being said, have you tried the same code with an `AsyncTaskLoader` instead?

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html